# Ruby Blog: Toto vs Nesta

Tags: ruby, heroku, nestacms, toto

I need a simple and lightweight blog engine that plays well with Heroku.

So far, I found [Toto](http://cloudhead.io/toto) and [Nesta](http://nestacms.com/) and both seem to be great candidates and have a rather similar feature list.

Since I have to make a quick decision Im interested in pragmatic comparison overview. Specifically first concern would be theming and in a lesser degree ease of extension- i.e. plugin support and dev...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'm a big fan of [Octopress](http://octopress.org/). It uses Jekyll in the background, is easy to [theme and customize](http://octopress.org/docs/theme/), has a nice list of features and [plugins](http://octopress.org/docs/blogging/plugins/), is easy to hack and generates static HTML, which is perfect for my needs.

BTW: this question is rather off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Nesta](http://nestacms.com) has gained the most traction so far - the mailing list is pretty active, and the plugin collection is growing. I recently migrated all my websites to it.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to try [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll)